# Can't connect ESP32 to MQTT

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp32

I have been trying to connect my ESP32 with HiveMQ MQTT broker url. It connects when I use free public MQTT broker like broker.hivemq.com, but when I use my url which I got after registering in HiveMQ, it doesn't connect. It returns error with code 2.

I have used this MQTT broker url with windows MQTT client app and it works fine but it doesn't work with ESP32.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// WiFi
const char *ssid = "********"; // Enter your WiFi name
const char *password = "********";  // Enter WiFi password

// MQTT Broker
const char *mqtt_broker = "591c2cacc87d4e248d106212ae6e0d4f.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud";
const char *topic = "esp32/test";
const char *mqtt_username = "*******";
const char *mqtt_password = "*******";
const int mqtt_port = 8883;

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
 // Set software serial baud to 115200;
 Serial.begin(115200);
 // connecting to a WiFi network
 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
     delay(500);
     Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
 }
 Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
 //connecting to a mqtt broker
 client.setServer(mqtt_broker, mqtt_port);
 client.setCallback(callback);
 while (!client.connected()) {
     String client_id = "esp32-client-";
     client_id += String(WiFi.macAddress());
     Serial.printf("The client %s connects to the public mqtt broker\n", client_id.c_str());
     if (client.connect(client_id.c_str(), mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
         Serial.println("Public emqx mqtt broker connected");
     } else {
         Serial.print("failed with state ");
         Serial.print(client.state());
         delay(2000);
     }
 }
 // publish and subscribe
 client.publish(topic, "Hi EMQ X I'm ESP32 ^^");
 client.subscribe(topic);
}

void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {
 Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
 Serial.println(topic);
 Serial.print("Message:");
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     Serial.print((char) payload[i]);
 }
 Serial.println();
 Serial.println("-----------------------");
}

void loop() {
 client.loop();
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as "JavaScript"?

Comment: The MQTT client app on windows which I mentioned about was made in Node.JS

Comment: When you use MQTT over TLS (port 8883), you need to use `WiFiClientSecure.h`  and add the root CA of broker.hivemq.com to your sketch. Refer to [WiFiClientSecure](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/examples/WiFiClientSecure/WiFiClientSecure.ino) on how to do it.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of WifiClientSecure with MQTT on Esp32? I'm not getting it. And how do I get root CA of HiveMQ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of Farhan's example and a few other examples I found elsewhere, I was able to get this to work.

1. First, open a terminal run the command from Johnny Boy's answer (This assumes you have openssl installed. If not, [install it](https://www.openssl.org/).

`openssl s_client -connect YOUR_URL.hivemq.cloud:8883 -showcerts`

2. You'll get three certificates. They look like this

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFYDCCBEigAwIBAgIQQAF3ITfU6UK47naqPGQKtzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
> MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
> DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTIxMDEyMDE5MTQwM1oXDTI0MDkzMDE4MTQwM1ow
> ...Lots more characters that I'll omit for brevity...
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

3. The third certificate is the one you want. Copy this certificate out of your terminal (including the BEGIN and END CERTIFICATE parts). Paste the cert into your ESP32 code as a const char variable, such as:

> const char *ROOT_CERT = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" 
> "MIIFYDCCBEigAwIBAgIQQAF3ITfU6UK47naqPGQKtzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/\n" 
> "MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT\n" 
> ... etc..

4. Using the WiFiClientSecure library mentioned in the comments, use the setCACert function to utilize your certificate. The rest of the code looks pretty close to what Farhan had. In my example, a few of the variables, including the ROOT_CERT variable from above, were defined in another file (WifiCredentials.h):

   ```
   #include <PubSubClient.h>
   #include <WiFi.h>
   #include <WiFiClient.h>
   #include <WiFiServer.h>
   #include <WiFiUdp.h>
   #include "WifiCredentials.h"
   #include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

   *********/
   Helpful  References: 
      * https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/
      * 
   *********/

   WiFiClientSecure wifiClient;
   PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient); 
   char *mqttServer = "YOUR_URL.hivemq.cloud";
   int mqttPort = 8883;
   const char *mqtt_password = "password_I_setup_at_hivemq";
   const char *mqtt_username = "username_I-setup_at_hivemq";

   void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);

     // Connect to Wi-Fi network
     Serial.print("Connecting to ");
     Serial.println(WifiSSID);
     WiFi.begin(WifiSSID, WifiPassword);
     while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
       delay(500);
       Serial.println("...Still Connecting");
     }

     Serial.println("");
     Serial.println("WiFi connected.");


     wifiClient.setCACert(ROOT_CERT);
   }

   void loop(){
     if (!mqttClient.connected()) {    
       mqttClient.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
       // set the callback function
       mqttClient.setCallback(callback);
       Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT Broker...");
       while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
         Serial.println("Reconnecting to MQTT Broker..");
         String clientId = "ESP32Client-";
         clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);

         if (mqttClient.connect(clientId.c_str(), mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
            Serial.println("Connected to MQTT BRoker!.");
            // subscribe to topic
            mqttClient.subscribe("/transactions/device1");
            mqttClient.publish("/transactions/device1", "testing hello");
         } else {
             Serial.print("failed with state ");
             Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
             delay(2000);
         }
        }
      }
      mqttClient.loop();
   }

   void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
     Serial.print("Callback - ");
     Serial.print("Message:");
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
     }
   }
   ```
5. Connect a tool like [MQTT Dash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.routix.mqttdash&hl=en_US&gl=US) to your HiveMQ instance, open a serial monitor, and test your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, [@hcheung said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4902099/hcheung):

> When you use MQTT over TLS (port 8883), you need to use `WiFiClientSecure.h` and add the root CA of `broker.hivemq.com` to your sketch. Refer to [`WiFiClientSecure`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/examples/WiFiClientSecure/WiFiClientSecure.ino) on how to do it.

You can get the root CA of your HiveMQ broker with the following OpenSSL method:

```
openssl s_client -connect hivemq-broker-host:8883 -showcerts
```

Change `hivemq-broker-host` with your MQTT host.